# Laravel OneToMany relation not linking the right data together

Tags: laravel

I'm currently developing a platform where i make use of a sql database in azure. 
I created a database with 3 tables.

Table A:
ID (PK, varchar)
Example ID: SK196AK

Table B:
ID (PK)
Name (VAR)
Version (INT)

Table C:
ID (PK)
path
a_id (Foreign Key of table A)
b_id (Foreign Key of table B)

In laravel i've made 3 models:

- IoTA
- IoTB
- IoTC

I've made a model for every table in the database.
For the relations i've added a function to the IoTC model where i return `$this->hasMany(IoTB::class, 'id');`

And i've added a funciton to the IoTB model where i return `$this->belongsTo(IoTC::class);`

In my controller i get all data from IoTC and pass it on to my view. 
I get all data using the following code:

```
$IoTC= IoTC::with('types')->get();
```

In my view i have a foreach loop where i loop through the data:

```
 @foreach ($IoTC as $iot)
      <tr>
          <td>{{ $iot->type_id}}</td>
          <td>{{ $iot->IotB}}</td>
          <td>{{ $iot->IoTB}}</td>
      </tr>

@endforeach
```

Now onto my problem, when i try to retrieve the data of the relation it show it like this:
[image: List]

As you can see my code shows the data but the relations arrent set correctly. So it shows the id in the left column and the data from the other model in the middle and right column. The ID's arrent linked correctly between the models. 
Can someone explain how something like this can happen?

Comment: I understand that your problem is you have equal IDs from table C related to different rows at table B, right? Just to make sure: is `type_id` your PK of table C? And have you checked the data directly from the database?

Comment: Type_id is the foreign key of table B. The ID in the left column should be equal to the ID returned in the middle column but in the middle column it just loops through all items in table b for some reason. I want to show the data that belongs to the id in the left column

Comment: I suppose you have set the relationships in the wrong way. 
IoTC has a FK to IoTB;
IoTC needs a belongsTo to IoTB and IoTB needs a hasMany to IoTC.

Please refer to Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many